# Jpanel inside another Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am facing a problem that i think its pretty easy to solve but i cannot figure it out.
So i have a main jpanel and i cannot insert another jpanel2 in a different class to it, the components from jpanel2 dont appear on the 1st one.
Here's the code for the 1st jpanel constructor:

```
 public PainelPrincipal(Jogo janela) {`  
    super();  
    painel = new JPanel(){  
        protected void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) { 
            super.paintComponents(g); 
            try{  
                g.drawImage(ImageIO.read(PainelPrincipal.class.getResource("Imagens/fundo/Fundo0.jpg")), 0, 0, this);  
            }catch(IOException e){  
                `e.printStackTrace();  
            } 
        };
    };  
    painel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));  
    janela.setContentPane(painel);  
    painel.setLayout(null);  
    painelBonus = new PainelBonus();  
    painelBonus.setBounds(199, 537, 352, 156);  
    painel.add(painelBonus);  

    painelVida = new PainelVida();
    painelVida.setBounds(856, 426, 73, 267);
    //painelVida.setBounds();
    painel.add(painelVida);

    lblPontuacao = new JLabel("Pontua\u00E7\u00E3o: 0");
    lblPontuacao.setForeground(new Color(255, 69, 0));
    lblPontuacao.setBounds(0, 0, 1024, 22);
    lblPontuacao.setBackground(new Color(128, 0, 0));
    lblPontuacao.setOpaque(true);
    lblPontuacao.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    painel.add(lblPontuacao);

    JLabel labelEsq = new JLabel("");
    labelEsq.setBackground(new Color(128, 0, 0));
    labelEsq.setOpaque(true);
    labelEsq.setBounds(0, 21, 11, 747);
    painel.add(labelEsq);

    GridPanel gridPanel_1 = new GridPanel();
    gridPanel_1.setBounds(10, 33, 767, 418);
    gridPanel_1.setShowGridLines(true);
    gridPanel_1.setRowSize(40);
    gridPanel_1.setColumnSize(40);
    gridPanel_1.setColumns(18);
    painel.add(gridPanel_1);

    JLabel labelDir = new JLabel("");
    labelDir.setOpaque(true);
    labelDir.setBackground(new Color(128, 0, 0));
    labelDir.setBounds(1013, 21, 11, 747);
    painel.add(labelDir);
}
```

This code painelBonus = new PainelBonus(); executes the constructor PainelBonus with all the components:

```
public PainelBonus() {  
    super();  
    painel = new JPanel();  
    painel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));  
    painel.setBorder(null);  
    painel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 157));  
    painel.setLayout(null);  

    imagemMartelo = new ImageIcon(PainelBonus.class.getResource("/Imagens/bonus/bonus_martelo/bonus_martelo_0.png"));
    imagemBomba = new ImageIcon(PainelBonus.class.getResource("/Imagens/bonus/bonus_bomba/bonus_bomba_0.png"));

    JButton btnImagemMartelo = new JButton("");
    btnImagemMartelo.setBounds(10, 11, 136, 136);
    btnImagemMartelo.setIcon(imagemMartelo);
    btnImagemMartelo.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    painel.add(btnImagemMartelo);

    JButton btnImagemBomba = new JButton("");
    btnImagemBomba.setBounds(154, 11, 136, 136);
    btnImagemBomba.setIcon(imagemBomba);
    btnImagemBomba.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    painel.add(btnImagemBomba);
}
```

Here's the problem: the components from PainelBonus doesn't seem to appear on PainelPrincipal

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p43oD.jpg

Sorry for bad formatting, kinda new here :D
TY Hovercraft Full Of Eels for the help on editing :D

Comment: Please format your code. It is very hard to read in the current configuration.

Comment: Could it be that you are calling super.paintComponents(g); rather than super.paintComponent(g); ?

Comment: PainelBonus creates another JPanel, but is never added to anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PainelBonus`, which seems to extend from `JPanel` (or some other `Component` based class) creates it's own `JPanel` (`painel = new JPanel();`) to which you add some components, but you never add that panel (`painel`) to `PainelBonus`

Equally, `PainelPrincipal` creates a `JPanel`, `painel` onto which you add other components, including `PainelBonus` but this panel (`painel`) is never added to anything.

Don't use `null` layouts. Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern UI design, you have no control over fonts, DPI, rendering pipelines or other factors that will change the way that you components will be rendered on the screen.

Swing was designed to work with layout managers to overcome these issues. If you insist on ignoring these features and work against the API design, be prepared for a lot of headaches and never ending hard work...

**Updated with an example**

```
public PainelPrincipal(Jogo janela) {`  
    super();  
    painel = new JPanel(){  
        protected void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) { 
            super.paintComponents(g); 
            try{  
                // You shouldn't be loading resources in the paint method
                // And infact, this could be achieved by using a JLabel instead
                // of creating a custom JPanel
                g.drawImage(ImageIO.read(PainelPrincipal.class.getResource("Imagens/fundo/Fundo0.jpg")), 0, 0, this);  
            }catch(IOException e){  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            } 
        };
    };  
    //...
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(painel);
}

public PainelBonus() {  
    super();  
    setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));  
    setBorder(null);  
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 157));  
    setLayout(null);  

    imagemMartelo = new ImageIcon(PainelBonus.class.getResource("/Imagens/bonus/bonus_martelo/bonus_martelo_0.png"));
    imagemBomba = new ImageIcon(PainelBonus.class.getResource("/Imagens/bonus/bonus_bomba/bonus_bomba_0.png"));

    JButton btnImagemMartelo = new JButton("");
    btnImagemMartelo.setBounds(10, 11, 136, 136);
    btnImagemMartelo.setIcon(imagemMartelo);
    btnImagemMartelo.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    add(btnImagemMartelo);

    JButton btnImagemBomba = new JButton("");
    btnImagemBomba.setBounds(154, 11, 136, 136);
    btnImagemBomba.setIcon(imagemBomba);
    btnImagemBomba.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    add(btnImagemBomba);
}
```

Comment: i tried to pass the 1st Panel (PainelPrincipal) by reference to the second panel(PainelBonus) like this:   public PainelBonus(JPanel painelPrinc) {   and then adding the PainelBonus to it:  painelPrinc.add(painel);  it didn't work

Comment: That's not the point.  The fact is, you don't need that inner panel to either of the two classes, simply add the content directly to them

Comment: the only problem is that its a school work, so i cannot mix it together all in one class, it should be organized in classes to represent what is what.

Comment: But `PainelBonus` and `PainelPrincipal` are `JPanel`s already?  Simply break down you requirements into small manageable chunks (which you seem to be doing) and add those elements you need together to form composite components.  Create a `JPanel` inside a `JPanel` but then not adding the second panel to anything is the root cause of your problem

Comment: I just can't seem to figure it out... tell me one thing: does this: ( public class PainelBonus extends JPanel{ ) AND ( public JPanel painel; ) creates 2 different panels? Like by extending the class to JPanel does it creates a useable JPanel or do i need to create another one like i did?

Comment: Yes.  If your class extends from `JPanel`, it is it's own instance of `JPanel`, creating a second `JPanel` within it will simply create it's own distinct instance

Comment: Yes that was definitely it! Thanks a lot for solving my problem and for the lesson on Java :D