# how to add jpanel to jpanel in java

Tags: java, eclipse, jpanel

I have a problem when i add a jpanel to existing jpanel!

i want jlist at center loction and jbuttom in south location!

i can see the jlist, but the jbuttom won't show on!

I'm using Eclipse 3.0 version.

this is my code:

```
package classes;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class JPanelDecorator extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JList<String> list = null;
    private JButton Change=null;

    public JPanelDecorator()
    {
        super();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());       
        setSize(450 ,400);
        String animals_list[] = new String[AquaPanel.swims.size()];
        LinkedList<Swimmable> ir = new LinkedList<Swimmable>(AquaPanel.swims);
        for(int i=0;i<ir.size();i++)
        {
            animals_list[i]=(i+1+". "+ir.get(i).toString());
        }

        list = new JList<String>(animals_list );
        list.setFont(new Font("Tahoma",Font.BOLD,15));
        list.setSize(450, 300);
        add(list,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        Change = new JButton("Change Color");
        Change.addActionListener(this);
        add(Change,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        repaint();
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    }

}
```

please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jpanel inside another Jpanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398214/jpanel-inside-another-jpanel)

Comment: Eclipse 3.0 is **twelve** years old!

Comment: @greg-449 working on 3.4.2 at the office,(flash builder 4.0) . An Netbeans 6.9.1, a 2010 release. This is not always possible to update the software ... still on java 6 here.

Answer (score 1):

You have a subtle bug. In the constructor of `JPanelDecorator` you have :

```
public JPanelDecorator()
{
    //....
    add(list,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //...
    add(Change,BorderLayout.CENTER); // center again...
    //...
}
```

But what you need is this:

```
public JPanelDecorator()
{
    //....
    add(list,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //...
    add(Change,BorderLayout.SOUTH); // south
    //...
}
```